# DotNetNuke -- Are All Logins Tracked Anywhere?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke

I know you can find the last time a user logged in from the Users table, in the column called "LastModifiedOnDate".  But I'm interested in finding the complete history of timestamps for when a user has logged in.  Is this possible?  If so, in what table is this info stored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an event stored in the Log Viewer (i.e. the `EventLog` table) for each successful login.  However, the default settings are to only store the last 10 of these events.  You can go to the Log Viewer page (under Admin) and edit the Log Settings, then edit the Login Success event to keep more entries.

Answer (score 3):

DotNetNuke `Events Module` is out of the box and already logs log-in and log-out activities.

The related table is `EventLogs`. If you need more in-depth logging, you can [Activate Site Logs](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/39/View/Details/How-to-activate-the-site-log-feature.aspx), and look at `sitelogs` table.

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps can also try admin>site log