# IIS log parser for DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to track number of times a page is viewed, my site is in production,

I tried using LogParser 2.2 but since I am using DotNetNuke I cannot give the exact page name, since every page is mentioned by TabID.

is there any way i can track this.

Comment: You can get help from these answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170998/dotnetnuke-are-all-logins-tracked-anywhere

Comment: I have used SurfStats for this. You can manually associate tabids with page names.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to do this is to parse from LogParser to get the TabId's then do a database cross reference.

My personal recommendation is to use Google Analytics for this as you get it by friendly name that way.

(People in the comments mention the site log, I strongly recommend against that for performance reasons.)